# following lodash error on build 'Cannot find name 'Exclude''

Tags: angular, typescript, lodash

I am getting following lodash error

> ERROR in node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1689,12): error
>   TS2304: Cannot find name 'Exclude'.
>   node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1766,12): error TS2304:
>   Cannot find name 'Exclude'.
>   node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1842,34): error TS2304:
>   Cannot find name 'Exclude'.

Comment: please share package.json code understand your problem

Comment: "typescript": "~2.7.2",   "@types/lodash": "^4.14.122", "lodash": "^4.17.10", "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.2", "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",

Answer (score 14):

**Solution 1** 
I also had the same issue, i tried to downgrade typescript version and lodash version, but nothing worked, and at last i tried installing @types/lodash, and it worked.
just try this:

```
npm i @types/lodash
```

hope it helps.

If the above solution doesn't work try this: 
 
**Solution 2** 
The actual issue is, Exclude was added to typescript on version 2.8. You might have a version of @types/lodash that needs minimum typescript 2.8, and it can happen if your lodash and typescript version didn't match.

So, install the last typescript 2.3 version compatible with lodash using this code :

```
npm i -D @types/lodash@ts2.3
```

Comment: This solution fixed my issue. Thanks dude

Answer (score 8):

I'm facing the same issue this morning. 
One possible solution for me is to fix the lodash version in the package.json :

`"lodash": "^4.17.4"` => `"lodash": "4.17.4"`

`"@types/lodash": "^4.14.55"` => `"@types/lodash": "4.14.55"`

And waiting for a more stable fix/solution.

Hope that works for you

Answer (score 6):

There are recent updates on lodash typings
reference : https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/lodash
Last updated: Mon, 04 Mar 2019 22:42:42 GMT

changing `"@types/lodash": "4.14.121"` worked for me as this was the most stable version referred prior to recent update.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same error for this evening. I try to re-install all of them but nothing happend.

Current I use:

Typescript: 2.2.2
- Ionic: 3, Ionic CLI: 4.1.2
- Cordova: 8.1.2
- Angular CLI: 1.2.4

My solution for now: Set the typesript version to 3.2.4 => It work for me

**Updated**
For now, I fix issue by force install the lodash: `npm install --save @types/lodash@4.14.118`

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem indirectly.

1. Find `@types/lodash` in `package-lock.json` 
   [image]
2. Update `package.json`
   [image]

Comment: First of all, welcome to StackOverflow. Following the advices of the community, it is recommended to include directly the images instead of links to better understand your response. 
Please check the documentation [on how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error since 2 days.

my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "prod": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.1",
    "angular2-json-schema-form": "https://github.com/ptv-ldts/angular2-json-schema-form/tarball/impact?v1.0.2",
    "angular2-notifications": "^0.7.3",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "clipboard": "^1.6.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-cheerio": "^0.6.2",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.3.2",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "ng2-ace-editor": "^0.1.9",
    "ng2-bs3-modal": "^0.10.4",
    "ng2-smart-table": "1.2.1",
    "ngx-clipboard": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.55",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "angular-ide": "^0.9.19",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0"
  }
}
```

Update: 
What I found was, that exclude comes in with typescript 2.8. I changed the line in package json for typescript to "typescript": "^2.2.0" and updated.

Comment: What do you mean you "updated"? I have changed the line in pakage.json but it doesn't work, do I need to run a command to make it take effect?

Answer (score 1):

We faced this issue and we had to increment the typescript version to "2.8" to solve the "Exclude" error.

Note: Make sure to use the typescript version which is required by your @angular/cli version.

Like, in my case @angluar/cli version is "6.0.8" which can accept typescript version "2.8".

Answer (score 1):

For me, it appeared to be a change of lodash from 4.14.118 -> 4.14.122.  Fixing at 4.14.118 fixed this issue.

"@types/lodash": "4.14.118",

Answer (score 0):

We have faced the same issue but it got resolved after I change the version of lodash from - `"@types/lodash": "^4.14.111"` to  `"@types/lodash": "4.14.121"` in the package.json file

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to update angular-tree-component from 7.2.0 to 8.2.0 and the problem got resolved!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue.
I solved it by installing lodash with below command

npm install --save @types/lodash@4.14.55

Check the version mentioned in Package.json and install corresponding version to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install older verison of typescript :
Example `npm i -D @types/lodash@ts2.5`