# lodash-es error on build 'Cannot find name 'Exclude'.'

Tags: angular, typescript, lodash

I am running into an issue similar to the one mentioned here ([following lodash error on build 'Cannot find name 'Exclude''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55018665/following-lodash-error-on-build-cannot-find-name-exclude/))

```
ERROR in ... /node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts (1689,12): Cannot find name 'Exclude'.
ERROR in ... /node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts (1766,12): Cannot find name 'Exclude'.
ERROR in ... /node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts (1842,34): Cannot find name 'Exclude'.
```

However, I am using the lodash-es packages vs. the full lodash packages and the reported solutions are not working for me.

I have the following relevant dependencies in my package.json file for my project:

"@types/lodash-es": "4.17.0",
"lodash-es": "4.17.4",
"typescript": "~2.3.2"

As best I can tell, it looks like @types/lodash-es was updated most recently on Mar  04 (see https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/lodash-es), however, I am not using this recently updated version, but am instead specifying 4.17.0 specifically.

The answers in to the related question suggest the solution is to point to a prior-to-breaking-changes package, but I have attempted this with no success.

What can be done to resolve this issue? A production build is breaking because of this...

Update:
In looking at the project's package-lock.json file, I found the following:

```
"@types/lodash": {
  "version": "4.14.123",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/lodash/-/lodash-4.14.123.tgz"
},
"@types/lodash-es": {
  "version": "4.17.0",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/lodash-es/-/lodash-es-4.17.0.tgz",
  "requires": {
    "@types/lodash": "*"
  }
},
```

It looks to me like when @types/lodash-es requires @types/lodash: *, that the latest version of @types/lodash (4.14.123 - which includes the breaking change) is being brought into the project.

How can I cause a different version of @types/lodash to be brought in when I don't control the package-lock.json entries made by my dependency "@types/lodash-es": "4.17.0" ?

Comment: `Exclude` is a conditional type introduced after 2.8. you seem o have ts `2.3.2`

Comment: I agree, that seems correct based on comments/answers in the other thread. However, because this is for an existing application, verifying changes to a significant Typescript update would be very difficult/not possible. It seems that whatever was updates in the most recent version of lodash-es, lodash were are not backwards compatible. 

I'm guessing/hopeful that the authors will address this, but my issue is that I can't update the Typescript version past 2.3.* and I should be able to build this project with previous versions of lodash-es, but that is not working for some reason.

Comment: In the project's package-lock.json file, I see the following entries, which includes a reference:
    "@types/lodash-es": {
      "version": "4.17.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/lodash-es/-/lodash-es-4.17.0.tgz",
      "requires": {
        "@types/lodash": "*"
      }
    }

And then a reference:
    "@types/lodash": {
      "version": "4.14.123",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/lodash/-/lodash-4.14.123.tgz",
    },

It looks like the lodash-es requires "*" might be causing the reference to lodash 4.14.123. Does this seem right?

Comment: npm uninstall @types/lodash, delete package-lock.json. run this command : npm install @types/lodash@4.14.108

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned, it seems that @types/lodash has introduced this problem in a recent update.

I fixed this problem by specifying an appropriate version of `@types/lodash` in my package.json.

As suggested in the responses to [the issue linked in the original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55018665/following-lodash-error-on-build-cannot-find-name-exclude/), this can be fixed by adding `"@types/lodash": "4.14.121"` to your package.json.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to install types for an old version of Typescript. For Typescript 2.5 it would be: `npm i -D @types/lodash@ts2.5`